# ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Getting ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege while running the below query on Oracle 11g r2 :

`grant inherit any privileges to dbuser1;`

Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion is to upgrade to at least 12c to use it. It doesn't exist in 11g, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

This privilege is first *documented* in [Oracle 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#LNPLS121)

### **INHERIT PRIVILEGES and INHERIT ANY PRIVILEGES Privileges**

> Before Oracle Database 12c, an IR unit always ran with the privileges of its invoker. If its invoker had higher privileges than its owner, then the IR unit might perform operations unintended by, or forbidden to, its owner.
>
> As of Oracle Database 12c, an IR unit can run with the privileges of its invoker only if its owner has either the INHERIT PRIVILEGES privilege on the invoker or the INHERIT ANY PRIVILEGES privilege.